# Convertir texto, en lista, sublistas y estas en diccionario

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de crear un archivo con un texto y convertirlo en una lista. Posteriormente dividir la lista en sub-listas.
Por último, convertir estas en un diccionario, pero me falta asignarle las keys al diccionario ¿qué me falta?

```
texto = """1;Carlos;Pérez;05/01/1989
2;Manuel;Heredia;26/12/1973
3;Rosa;Campos;12/06/1961
4;David;García;25/07/2006"""
```

## Creamos el nuevo documento y lo escribimos con el texto anterior

```
fichero = open ("personas.txt", "w", encoding = "utf8")
fichero.write (texto)
fichero.close()

fichero = open ("personas.txt", "r")
texto = fichero.readlines()

fichero.close()

print(type(texto))
print(texto)
print("\n")

for i,personas in enumerate (texto):
    print (i,personas)

print("\n")
```

## Dividimos la lista en sub-listas

```
id = []
nombre = []
apellido = []
bday = []
for i in texto:
    i, n, a, b = i.split(";")
    id.append (i)
    nombre.append (n)
    apellido.append (a)
    bday.append (b)

print (id)
print (nombre)
print (apellido)
print (bday)
print("\n")
```

## Unimos listas para convertirlo en un diccionario

```
personas = {}

personas=[list(x) for x in zip(nombre,apellido,bday)]
dict(zip(id,personas))


print("\n") 

for i in personas:
    for k,v in i.items():
        print (k,v)
```

---

Muchas gracias Candid Moe, ahora me encuentro con el siguiente TypeError y me vuelvo a atrancar.
Una vez corregido el código como me indicaste, necesito iterar el diccionario con un formato, pero al poner el for me da distintos tipos de error.

## Unimos listas para convertirlo en un diccionario

```
personas = {}
personas = {id[i]: (nombre[i], apellido[i], bday[i]) for i in 
range(len(apellido))}
```

## Iteramos y mostramos con formato predefinido:

```
for id in personas.items():
print ("(id={}) {} \t{} \t{}".format(id[i], nombre[i], apellido[i], bday[i]))
```

Muchas gracias de nuevo

Comment: El primer dato de cada línea es el `id`. Esa es la llave que buscas. Es como funciona en la vida real: tienes un número asignado por el Estado que usas como identidad para trámites, bancos, etc.

Comment: si, lo se pero ¿cómo lo convierto en la key del diccionario?

Comment: No veo problema con tu código, con la excepción de que estás modificando la variable `personas` con una lista, y que el diccionario no se lo asignas a nada. Pero es mejor que sigas la respuesta de @CandidMoe .Usando _comprensiones de diccionarios_ es más legible y menos propenso a fallos.

Comment: Si los "#" eran comentarios, indenta como corresponde el código. Esos títulos son enormes...

Answer (score 0):

Para crear un diccionario con comprensión se usa:

```
diccionario = {k: v for some_expression}
```

La clave es usar "{}" y separar la llave y el valor con un ":". Llave y valor son expresiones.

En este caso sería:

```
nombre = ["juan", "raul"]
apellido = ["pere<", "soto"]
bday = ["1/1/2000", "2/2/2000"]
id = ["01", "02"]

diccionario = {id[i]: (nombre[i], apellido[i], bday[i]) for i in range(len(nombre))}

print(diccionario)
```

El valor es una 3-tupla (nombre,apellido,bday). Puedes usar una lista también o cualquier otro objeto de tu conveniencia.

La llave es el id. Dado que todas las listas tienen que ser del mismo largo, usamos el largo de una para controlar la iteración.

El resultado es:

```
{'01': ('juan', 'pere<', '1/1/2000'), '02': ('raul', 'soto', '2/2/2000')}

Process finished with exit code 0
```